# Scroll viewpager inside recyclerview

Tags: android

I have a big problem. I have a viewpager inside recyclerview, viewpager can drag left or right. And I want when viewpager pulled vertically the recyclerview must be rolled. But this is difficult for me. 
Would you give way to help solve this problem for me, Thanks !

Comment: why you need to use viewpager inside recyclerview? because it can manage recylcerview inside viewpager.so what is your actual requirements?becase behalf of this,it will change scenario.

Comment: Try to check below : http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/11/android-recyclerview-scrolling-behaviour.html